# Duplicate rows in databse when parsing xml file using xml.nodes

Tags: sql, xml, duplicates

I have successfully parsed most of my XML file into my database however I have an issue with the following nodes/data.

**XML data example:**

[image]

I set up a case when for each different travel type however it has duplicated the lines in the db for each of the case whens. Any ideas on how to avoid this?

```
SELECT

 XC.value('../../@TransactionType', 'varchar(50)') TransactionType,
 XC.value('../../@OrderItemRef', 'bigint')OrderRef,
 XC.value('../../@TransactionDate', 'datetime')TransDate,
 XC.value('../@JourneyTime', 'int')JourneyTime,
 XC.value('../@Distance', 'nvarchar(10)' )Distance,
 XC.value('@Ref', 'varchar(50)' )TicketRef,
 ADC.value('@Organisation', 'varchar(50)' )Client,
 ACC.value('@ExternalRef', 'varchar(50)' )Account,
 DCC.value('@Address[1]', 'varchar(50)' )contactEmail,
 BAC.value('@FirstName','varchar(50)' ) + ' ' + BAC.value         ('@LastName','varchar(50)' ) Booker,
 PC.value('@FirstName','varchar(50)' )travellerforename,
 PC.value('@LastName','varchar(50)' )travellersurname,
 ORC.value('@Name','Varchar(50)' )Origin,
 DESTC.value('@Name','Varchar(50)' )Destination,
 XC.value('@Route', 'varchar(50)' )Route,
 XC.value('@Class' , 'varchar(50)' )Class,
 XC.value('@Code' , 'varchar(50)' )TicketCode,
 XC.value('@Name' , 'varchar(50)' )TicketType,
 TOPC.value('@Name' , 'varchar(50)' )TrainOperator,
 LEGC.value('@Departure' , 'Datetime' )TravelDate,
 FAREC.value('@TotalAmount' , 'nvarchar(10)' )Fare,
 FAREXC.value('@OfferedFare' , 'nvarchar(10)' )LowFare,
 FAREXC.value('@NormalFare' , 'nvarchar(10)' )HighFare,
 IDC.value('../@DeliveryMethod' , 'nvarchar(10)' )fulfilmentType,
 FAREXC.value('@Reason' , 'varchar(50)' ) travelreason,

 case when(CEC.value('@TransportType' , 'varchar(50)') = 'Rail') then
 CEC.value('@Emissions', 'decimal(4,2)')
 END AS [railCo2],
   case when(CEC.value('@TransportType' , 'varchar(50)') = 'Aeroplane') then
CEC.value('@Emissions', 'decimal(4,2)')
END AS [airCo2],
  case when(CEC.value('@TransportType' , 'varchar(50)') = 'Car - Diesel') then
CEC.value('@Emissions', 'decimal(4,2)')
END AS [CarDieselCo2],
case when(CEC.value('@TransportType' , 'varchar(50)') = 'Car - Petrol') then
CEC.value('@Emissions', 'decimal(4,2)')
END AS [CarDieselCo2],
case when(CEC.value('@TransportType' , 'varchar(50)') = 'Motorcycle') then
CEC.value('@Emissions', 'decimal(4,2)')
END AS [MotorcycleCo2]

FROM TempXML

cross apply
XMLData.nodes('my:Handoff/ImmediateDetail') AS IDT(IDC)
Cross Apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Ticket') AS XT(XC)
Cross apply 
IDC.nodes('AccountContact/Address') AS ADT(ADC)
Cross apply 
IDC.nodes('Account') AS ACT(ACC)
Cross apply 
IDC.nodes('DeliveryContact/Email') AS DCT(DCC)
cross apply 
IDC.nodes('BookingAgent/Person') AS BAT(BAC)
cross apply 
IDC.nodes('PassengerGroup/Passenger/Person') AS PT(PC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Origin') AS ORT(ORC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Destination') AS DESTT(DESTC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Leg[1]') AS LEGT(LEGC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Leg[1]/TOC') AS TOPT(TOPC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Ticket/Sale/Fare') AS FARET(FAREC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Ticket/FareException') AS FAREXT(FAREXC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/CarbonEmissionDetails/CarbonEmissions') AS CET(CEC)


WHERE 

LEGC.value('@Direction'  , 'varchar(50)' ) = 'Outbound'
```

**Output looks like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not show enough of you query, but my magic glass bulb tells me, that you are using `APPLY YourXML.nodes(...) AS x(CEC)` to retrieve the values *row-by-row*. Each row carries one value, so your result-set will have one value per row.

**Take away this `.nodes()`-call** and try something like this instead:

```
SELECT SomeColumns
      ,YourXml.value(N'(//CarbonEmissions[@TransportType="Rail"]/@Emission)[1]',N'decimal(10,4)') AS railCo2 
      ,YourXml.value(N'(//CarbonEmissions[@TransportType="Aeroplane"]/@Emission)[1]',N'decimal(10,4)') AS airCo2
      
      ,more columns like this
```

The idea is: Do a *deep search* (hence the `//` before `CarbonEmissions`) and find the first element, where the `TransportType` is equal to the string given.

In general it is better to specify the full (or relative) `XPath` rather than perform a deep search, so it might be better to use a longer path instead of `//CarbonEmissions`, but I don't know your XML...

### UPDATE

My magic glass bulb whispers something like this:

- just removed one node from the last `apply .nodes()`
- call the elements directly without a `case`

Good luck!

```
SELECT

 XC.value('../../@TransactionType', 'varchar(50)') TransactionType,
 XC.value('../../@OrderItemRef', 'bigint')OrderRef,
 XC.value('../../@TransactionDate', 'datetime')TransDate,
 XC.value('../@JourneyTime', 'int')JourneyTime,
 XC.value('../@Distance', 'nvarchar(10)' )Distance,
 XC.value('@Ref', 'varchar(50)' )TicketRef,
 ADC.value('@Organisation', 'varchar(50)' )Client,
 ACC.value('@ExternalRef', 'varchar(50)' )Account,
 DCC.value('@Address[1]', 'varchar(50)' )contactEmail,
 BAC.value('@FirstName','varchar(50)' ) + ' ' + BAC.value         ('@LastName','varchar(50)' ) Booker,
 PC.value('@FirstName','varchar(50)' )travellerforename,
 PC.value('@LastName','varchar(50)' )travellersurname,
 ORC.value('@Name','Varchar(50)' )Origin,
 DESTC.value('@Name','Varchar(50)' )Destination,
 XC.value('@Route', 'varchar(50)' )Route,
 XC.value('@Class' , 'varchar(50)' )Class,
 XC.value('@Code' , 'varchar(50)' )TicketCode,
 XC.value('@Name' , 'varchar(50)' )TicketType,
 TOPC.value('@Name' , 'varchar(50)' )TrainOperator,
 LEGC.value('@Departure' , 'Datetime' )TravelDate,
 FAREC.value('@TotalAmount' , 'nvarchar(10)' )Fare,
 FAREXC.value('@OfferedFare' , 'nvarchar(10)' )LowFare,
 FAREXC.value('@NormalFare' , 'nvarchar(10)' )HighFare,
 IDC.value('../@DeliveryMethod' , 'nvarchar(10)' )fulfilmentType,
 FAREXC.value('@Reason' , 'varchar(50)' ) travelreason,

 CEC.value(N'(CarbonEmissions[@TransportType="Rail"]/@Emission)[1]',N'decimal(10,4)') AS railCo2, 
 CEC.value(N'(CarbonEmissions[@TransportType="Aeroplane"]/@Emission)[1]',N'decimal(10,4)') AS airCo2

--more of the same

FROM TempXML

cross apply
XMLData.nodes('my:Handoff/ImmediateDetail') AS IDT(IDC)
Cross Apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Ticket') AS XT(XC)
Cross apply 
IDC.nodes('AccountContact/Address') AS ADT(ADC)
Cross apply 
IDC.nodes('Account') AS ACT(ACC)
Cross apply 
IDC.nodes('DeliveryContact/Email') AS DCT(DCC)
cross apply 
IDC.nodes('BookingAgent/Person') AS BAT(BAC)
cross apply 
IDC.nodes('PassengerGroup/Passenger/Person') AS PT(PC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Origin') AS ORT(ORC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Destination') AS DESTT(DESTC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Leg[1]') AS LEGT(LEGC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Leg[1]/TOC') AS TOPT(TOPC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Ticket/Sale/Fare') AS FARET(FAREC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/Ticket/FareException') AS FAREXT(FAREXC)
cross apply
IDC.nodes('Segment[1]/CarbonEmissionDetails') AS CET(CEC)


WHERE 

LEGC.value('@Direction'  , 'varchar(50)' ) = 'Outbound'
```

Comment: Hi sorry I know the rest of the SQL works so I didn't really consider posting it all - I will post the whole thing in a few minutes.

Comment: Hi SQL added above for you. Cheers

Comment: @DaveEdmonds It would help to provide a copy'n'pasteable (reduced) sample XML.

Comment: Hi no can do I am afraid. Data security is tight. I do appreciate that it limits you to how much you can assist. I will look at your advice above and see  if I can make it work. Thanks, Dave

Comment: @DaveEdmonds If I'd see this XML I'm pretty sure this could be done better / more straight... Maybe - if performance matters - you want to prepare a test sample... Anyway, I just placed an UPDATE after asking my magic glass bulb...

Comment: I will test and let you know the outcome. Many thanks for your time and help. Dave

Comment: @DaveEdmonds I'm curious, does my magic glass bulb needs cleaning or does it still work correctly? :-)

Comment: Hi, I am testing it right now and all is working great. Many thanks for all your help. Dave